# How to align background on both sides of page?

Tags: html, css

I need to have a centered div with page content, and repetitive background that is aligned separately on left and right side of page: [image: What it looks like now]. On the left side the arrow pattern should start where the left side of page ends and repeat to the end of left side of screen, and the same thing on the right side. On the right side it is aligned properly but it's coincidence. Current code is in: [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jhcsp/)

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="content">
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
* {
   min-height: 100%;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}
body {
   background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/mcX3gBy.png');
   background-attachment: fixed;
}
.container {
   min-height: 100%;
}
.content {
   margin: 0 auto;
   width: 150px;
   background-color: #fff;
   min-height:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, this can be done however it won't be that pretty.. You'll have to change your structure to create 2 parts of the background (even css3's multiple background won't help in this case).

[Here the working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jhcsp/9/)

I've added inside `.container` the following:

```
<div class="leftBG"></div>
<div class="rightBG"></div>
```

And added the CSS:

```
.leftBG{
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    width:50%;
    height:100%;
    z-index:1;
    background:url('http://i.imgur.com/mcX3gBy.png') top right repeat;
}

.rightBG{
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:auto;
    right:0px;
    width:50%;
    height:100%;
    z-index:1;
    background:url('http://i.imgur.com/mcX3gBy.png') top left repeat;
}
```

What this does is basically dividing the background in to 2 parts - left and right, each has it's own background when the left background is aligned to the left and the right background aligned to the right.

Comment: Background still doesnt start where the middle block ends, it should look like [this](http://i.imgur.com/VNczttR.png) Maybe the right and left divs should end not in middle but on sides of the center div?

Comment: Yes, but it is not aligned to the side of center div... First background block should start right where the middle block ends and not behind it

Comment: I think the solution with right and left divs is correct, but they should end on the sides of the center block, I'm just not sure how to accomplish that.

Comment: @user1766392 look at the updated answser - code and jsFiddle - removed `background-attachment:fixed`